# AutoMapper not playing nicely with SetUpFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper, automapper

Environment: C#, Visual Studio 2015, Resharper

We have a project that depends heavily on Automapper.
Naturally that means our tests depend heavily on Automapper's mapping being present.

Unfortunately, the map registration process is reasonably slow (it's Reflection based).

Originally, we were registering maps in the SetUp methods for each test. I managed to get our test suite to go from taking 20-25 minutes to run, down to ~7 minutes to run, by moving the registration to the TestFixtureSetUp (i.e. runs once per Class, not once per Test).

But that's still a lot of invocations as we have many test classes.
So I wanted to move to having a SetUpFixture at the top of each TestProject, and have the registrations happen once per Project, rather than once per Class.

At the first glance this worked well - running individual tests still worked, and running individual Classes' worth of tests still worked.

But if I try to run all the tests in a test project (either in the R# UnitTest manager, or in Jenkins by committing the changes) then everything fails as though the Registration hasn't happened.

Does anyone have any ideas of why this would be happening?

I have a horrible feeling that the answer is something to do with how the tests get executed and what threads/contexts exist and get created/destroyed.
Any suggestions for how to test this theory?

Comment: Are these NUnit tests? If so, which version?

Comment: Yes. (Have now added tag) Appears to be v2.6.4

Comment: _"move to having a SetUpFixture at the top of each TestProject"_ - outside of the namespace so all test classes pick it up?